# Android menu icon from a shape drawable

Tags: android, xml, drawable, menuitem

Does anyone know if its possible to use an XML ShapeDrawable (or any other XML drawable which is not an image) as a menu item icon? Is this not possible? and if it is, how does one go about achieving this?

TIA!

Comment: Yes, your drawable can be an XML drawable. You reference it the same way in your menu XML with `android:icon=@drawable/..."`

Comment: Inside <shape> tag give it a fixed <size>

Comment: Would you happen to have a working example/snippet of this? Would be great if you could please share?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: @pskink: You the man! Thanks. Completely missed the size attribute.

Comment: Yes,  i know i am the man!  ;-)

Comment: @pskink could you please add your comment as an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

It has been a bit since i've done android development, but with JB you would place it in your resources and reference it from the app manifest (I believe that's it?)

Comment: Place what? I am using a ShapeDrawable from my res/drawable directory but it does not show up at all. I guess it "may" probably be because there is no size information associated with a ShapeDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing that. You can change icon programmatically

`menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));`

or you can fix an icon in your menu.xml file

`android:icon="@drawable/ic_whaterver"`

Answer (score 0):

pskink said it in the comments (but it's easier to find as an answer). Give the drawable a `<size>` tag.

This is actually a little weird to me. Often, the size is used only to get the aspect ratio of a `<shape>`, so one might assume that setting size with `android:height="1"` and `android:width="1"` would suffice. Not so in this case - the drawable will appear with a size of 1x1 dp (probably not at all).

Interestingly, if you set the size to be much larger than the menu item, it is scaled down appropriately. So you can set the `android:height` and `android:width` to be something outrageous like `800dp` and not worry.